# Create elements in a loop and use different values

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create on-the-fly an `a` element and to set it an on-click function with alert.
I am familiar with the closure in JavaScript so I am aware of that I cannot call it directly like `doc.onclick=function() {alert(i);}` since it will have the value of the last `i`. so I tried to call the function immediately but it's also popup the alert immediately. how can I solve this issue?

```
  for (var i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
       var doc = document.createElement("a");
       doc.innerHTML = i;
       doc.onclick = function(i) {alert(i);}(i);
       document.body.appendChild(doc);
   }
```

Comment: I think you are trying to emulate the following: `doc.onclick = function () { alert(this.innerHTML); };` or `doc.addEventListener('click', function () { alert(this.innerHTML); });`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return a function in the closure here. Just calling your function immediately won't work, as you discovered.

```
for (var i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
   var doc = document.createElement("a");
   doc.innerHTML = i;
   doc.onclick = function(i) {
       return function(){alert(i);};
   }(i);
   document.body.appendChild(doc);
}
```

Comment: Thanks both yours and @marsh solution is working properly. 
but which solution is the best practice approach?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference. Whichever is easier for you to use and understand (including looking at the code 2 years from now).

Answer (score 4):

You should wrap something like this:

```
for (var i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
       var doc = document.createElement("a");
       doc.innerHTML = i;
        (function(i){
           doc.onclick = function() {
               alert(i);
           };
        })(i)
       document.body.appendChild(doc);
   }
```

This way adds `i` to closure, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hr1vphac/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
  for (var i=0; i < 5; ++i) {
      var doc = document.createElement("a");
      doc.innerHTML = i;
      document.body.appendChild(doc);
      doc.onclick = function() {alert(this.innerHTML);};
  }
```

Comment: also, see it live in action @ this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3Lv016ja/ it alerts the clicked number, that's what you're looking for right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish in the event handler but perhaps use [`EventTarget.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener):

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  var doc = document.createElement("a");
  doc.innerHTML = i;
  doc.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(this.textContent);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(doc);
}
```